# I need help to create a Report Builder in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, reporting

I have a challenge to create a "Report Builder", which aims to allow the creation of financial reports in a customized way from existing editable components.
I haven't found a library that is able to supply what I need, so I believe that the best thing is to build it in parts. I need some help to architect the application.

The first requirements of Report Builder:

- A "page" component for the report
- A list of components used for a build the report

  - (Example of components: Title, Text, Bar Graph, Column Graph, Table)
  - Each component can be individually editable according to its type
  - A component can be resizable
  - You can have more than one component
- The component can be dragged on the report page and placed in the desired location
- The report must be saved and its editing continued later

An existing project that has something very similar to what I need is FathomHQ Reporting.
Its Reporting is showed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz-CpLcBO7M

I'm thinking about using DNDKit (https://dndkit.com/) to drag and drop the report, but I'm still not sure how I can keep track of each individual component, and allow that it can be editable.

If anyone has any  library or architectural recommendation for building this project, I'll be glad to hear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.